# async load iframe in react

Tags: reactjs, iframe, redux

I am using an iframe on the webpage which is blocking the rest of the page from rendering until the iframe is completely loaded. How can I enable an async iframe load (or delay the load of the iframe) so the web page element isn't blocked?  *the iframe is not providing async loading.

Answer (score 3):

You could initialize the iframe after your `componentDidMount` like this:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showIframe: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({showIframe: true});
    }

    render() {
        const { showIframe } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                { showIframe && 
                    <iframe src={'https://www.example.com'} />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This will render the iframe after your component has mounted.